# Replace part of string between quotes in php regex

Tags: php, regex, substring, quotes, double-quotes

Now I've got very basic regex skills, only used regex a couple of times for basic stuff. This has probably been asked before, which I apologize for, but I couldn't find any answer for this. Found similar, though and tried to adapt it but to no avail.
OK, to the question - How do I replace a space only between certain characters (doublequotes in this case)?

Say i have the following string:

> "mission podcast" modcast A B C "D E F"

I want to replace the spaces between **mission** and **podcast** as well as the ones between **D**, **E** & **F** whilst leaving the other ones untouched.

P.S. What if space was a string? An example for that is welcome as well.

Edited this a bit I hope now it's more clear.
Edit 2: I need to do this on a string in php and execute it in the shell.
Edit 3: I'm sorry i changed the whole question 3 times it's just i'm getting quite confused myself. Cheers!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: can you provide more example other than `find /vol_stor/8s8a912hj1 | grep ""mission\|podcast"" | grep "modcast"` ? at least 2 variant will be much help

Comment: well, i haven't tried anything since i don't know how to preserve part of the matched string within and only replace what's within the words which are between the brackets. So, I am open to all kinds of suggestions :)

Comment: replace this regex `(")("\w+)(.*?)(\w+")(")` with `$2 $4`

Comment: one bracket = 1 group and you can represent that 1 group as one $ when replacing it. you just need to add which group you want to add. and you can add additional strings too into that replace.

Comment: Why is PHP one of the tags?

Comment: I tried Angga suggestion but i couldn't figure it out. do i need to put these inside the quotes with a space withing them? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to just get rid of any non-alphabet characters with a single space?

Comment: [go to this link](http://regexr.com?35eeq), that link will show you how i parse (your first example before edit) `find /vol_stor/8s8a912hj1 | grep ""mission\|podcast"" | grep "modcast"` to `"mission podcast"`

Comment: and after you edited your question, your bold text become very random. please fix that source string and your expected value from that string

Comment: omg i just can't get it to bold what i want :( I want to preserve the words but change the space in the middle but leave all of the other spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

I would attack this problem by first splitting the string into groups of either quoted or not quoted strings.

Then iterating through the matches and if Capture Group 1 is populated, then that string is quoted so just do a simple replace on replace Capture Group 0. If Capture group 1 is not populated then skip to the next match.

On each iteration, you'd want to simply build up a new string.

Since splitting the string is the difficult part, I'd use this regex:

`("[^"]*")|[^"]*`

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

```
"mission podcast" modcast A B C "D E F"
```

**Code**

```
PHP Code Example: 
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/("[^"]*")|[^"]*/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Capture Groups**

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "mission podcast"
            [1] =>  modcast A B C 
            [2] => "D E F"
            [3] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "mission podcast"
            [1] => 
            [2] => "D E F"
            [3] => 
        )

)
```

## PHP Example

This php script will replace only the spaces inside quoted strings.

Working example: http://ideone.com/jBytL3

**Code**

```
<?php

$text ='"mission podcast" modcast A B C "D E F"';

preg_match_all('/("[^"]*")|[^"]*/',$text,$matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $entry){
    echo preg_replace('/\s(?=.*?")/ims','~~new~~',$entry);
    }
```

**Output**

```
"mission~~new~~podcast" modcast A B C "D~~new~~E~~new~~F"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for taking the time to illustrate it! And as it would do perfect, i was hoping i could avoid splitting into arrays. Do you have any suggestion with **preg_replace** instead?

Comment: actually it was the foreach statement i was trying to avoid, but, anyways this does perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: What if the space was a string? Can i match a whole string?

Comment: nevermind i figured it out. if any noob like me is wondering, the **\s** in `echo preg_replace('/\s(?=.*?")/ims','~~new~~',$entry);` should be replaced with the string you want to replace. Thanks very much everyone!

Comment: Could you explain the `(?=.*?")` part in the last regex?

Comment: Nevermind I found that `(?=` is called "lookakead" and I was able to learn how to use it here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @TomasM yeah, that site rocks. It's cleanly describes how Regular Expressions work.

Comment: `ims` is not necessary.  Only `s` actually does anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use regular expressions, here is an iterative version that works:

```
<?php
    function remove_quoted_whitespace($str) {
        $result = '';
        $length = strlen($str);
        $index = 0;
        $in_quotes = false;

        while ($index < $length) {
            $c = $str[$index++];

            if ($c == '"') {
                $in_quotes = !$in_quotes;
            } else if ($c == ' ') {
                if ($in_quotes) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $result .= $c;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    $input = '"mission podcast" modcast A B C "D E F"';
    $output = remove_quoted_whitespace($input);

    echo $input . "\n";
    echo $output . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: yes, but isn't iterating more resource intensive, doesn't it take longer?

Comment: Just ran a head-to-head test and (against my intuition) the regular expression implementation is indeed faster.  I'm chalking it up to the difference between native code (the PCRE extension is implemented in C) vs. interpreted PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The entire foreach is not needed at all! It is possible to use a one-liner for this.

Here is the code which replaces spaces in quoted strings. The idea is that if a space is inside quotes, it is followed by odd number of quotes. It can be done by regexp look-ahead.

```
echo preg_replace('{\s+(?!([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)}',"x",$str);
```

That's all! How it works? It matches all \s characters which are not followed by even number of quotes. The matching spaces get replaced by x. You can of course change it to any desired value or leave it empty.

Comment: this stops working if you don't have a closing quote somewhere, so imagine a string that has multiple quoted text segments, and you leave a closing quote off, it goes wacky