# Java Regex To Remove unwanted characters from String except for characters in double quotes

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

We have a JAVA String as

```
String str = "WHERE geoAreaName=\"Barcelona (Spain) EUR\" AND (startDate=\"2019-01-01\" AND  endDate=\"2020-01-01\")";
```

We need to remove characters like `[ , ], ( , ), { , }` from it.

The regex pattern to identify the same is : `[\\[\\](){}]`

So on executing below code, the output is:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]" , ""));

>>> WHERE geoAreaName="Barcelona Spain EUR" AND startDate="2019-01-01" AND endDate="2020-01-01"
```

This works fine, except we need to keep the data enclosed in double quotes intact.

`Barcelona (Spain) EUR` needs to be intact and not converted to `Barcelona Spain EUR`

The expected output is :

```
WHERE geoAreaName="Barcelona (Spain) EUR" AND startDate="2019-01-01" AND endDate="2020-01-01"
```

So in a nutshell, I need a regex which will identify the characters in given string except for the parts which are in quotes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you edit the SQL string in your java code with regex? Why do you want to remove the bracket characters? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Actually I went with SQL example just to explain the problem better. This problem is in regex domain and thing Im looking for is `a regex which will identify and replace the characters in given string except for the parts which are in quotes.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Regex be used for this particular string manipulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138552/can-regex-be-used-for-this-particular-string-manipulation)

Comment: You might also want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Comment: And maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431820/replace-part-of-string-between-quotes-in-php-regex as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to remove the parentheses from your `WHERE` clause outside of string literals.  They are superfluous, but there is nothing wrong with them being there.  However, you have another problem, namely that you are using double quotes for string and date literals when you should be using single quotes.  So I actually suggest the following replacement:

```
String where = "WHERE geoAreaName=\"Barcelona (Spain) EUR\" AND (startDate=\"2019-01-01\" AND  endDate=\"2020-01-01\")";
where = where.replaceAll("\"", "'");
```

The resulting `WHERE` clause is perfectly valid and should run as you expect:

```
WHERE
    geoAreaName = 'Barcelona (Spain) EUR' AND
    (startDate = '2019-01-01' AND  endDate = '2020-01-01')
```

Comment: Actually I went with SQL example just to explain the problem better. This problem is in regex domain and thing Im looking for is `a regex which will identify and replace the characters in given string except for the parts which are in quotes.`
Even if we go with your solution, the brackets are still there.

Comment: @hemantvsn To handle your requirement in the general case you would need to write a SQL _parser_, not just a single regex.